# Shallow Copy in Java

Tags: java, constructor, copy

I already know, what a shallow copy is, but I'm not able to impliment it. Here's a short example.

```
public class Shallow {
String name;
int number;

 public Shallow (Shallow s) {
  this.name = s.name;
  this.number = s.number;
 }
}
```

Test the implementation ...

```
public class ShallowTest {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Shallow shallow  = new Shallow("Shallow", 123);
 Shallow shallowClone = new Shallow(shallow);
    shallowClone.name = 'Peter';
    shallowClone.number = 321;
    System.out.println(shallow.name + " - " + shallow.number);
}
}
```

As I purpose, just the reference of the non primitive datatype String would be copied, so that by calling "shallowClone.name = 'Peter';" I would also change the name of "shallow". Am I right? But somehow, it just does not want to work ....

Comment: How does the `new Shallow(shallow)` constructor code look like? You didn't include it in the question while the problem is likely caused right there. Noted should also be that strings are immutable.

Comment: Just edited the constructor.
Furthermore: I actually like just to copy the reference of the objects - it's the goal ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings and ints are immutable. Revise your data structure to use a mutable structure which holds references, such as an array or collection. E.g.

```
public class Shallow {
    private Object[] properties = new Object[2];

    public Shallow(String name, int number) {
        this.properties[0] = name;
        this.properties[1] = number;
    }

    public Shallow(Shallow s) {
        this.properties = s.properties;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return (String) properties[0];
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.properties[0] = name;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return (Integer) properties[1];
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.properties[1] = number;
    }
}
```

And use getters/setters instead of directly accessing the properties.

```
Shallow shallow = new Shallow("Shallow", 123);
Shallow shallowClone = new Shallow(shallow);
shallowClone.setName("Peter");
shallowClone.setNumber(321);
System.out.println(shallow.getName() + " - " + shallow.getNumber()); // Peter - 321
```

Also note that strings are usually to be quoted by doublequotes. In the future, *please* copypaste the actual, compileable and working code from your editor instead of typing it over or from top of head. Avoid red herrings.

Comment: Well, ok. I think I've got it! Thank you very much :)